# CKEditor - my styles in editor.css aren't being applied

Tags: javascript, html, css, ckeditor

I'm trying to change the default font color / size etc in the area of my ckeditor instance, but it's not working for me.

In chrome inspector I can add this style to the header and it works:

```
.cke_editable { 
    color: #fff; 
    font-size: 14px; 
    font-family: "Calibri";
}
```

However when I add this to my editor.css it has no effect. I've tried at the start and at the end, with no success. When I reload and check the resources in inspector, the correct css file *is* being loaded. Why aren't my styles applied?

When I inspect the iframe the `style` tag in the header doesn't contain the styles either.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Figured it out by removing my config and re-adding it a part at a time.

The very first line was

```
fullPage: true,
```

I had copied this from another source which used fullpage. I don't need it so I removed it.

According to the documentation, having fullPage on will stop contentsCss being implemented. From the ckeditor [documentation](http://docs.ckeditor.com/#!/api/CKEDITOR.config-cfg-contentsCss):

> Note: This configuration value is ignored by inline editor as it uses the styles that come directly from the page that CKEditor is rendered on. It is also ignored in the full page mode in which developer has a full control over the HTML.

However, what they fail to mention is that having fullPage set to true will also stop any changes to editor.css from being loaded. Once it was removed my custom styles shined through

Handy tip:

`contentsCSS` does *not* have to point to a css file. You can put straight css in there instead of a url, like so

```
contentsCss: '.cke_editable { color: #fff; font-family: Calibri; font-size: 14px; } ',
```

This will apply these styles directly to the editor. This appears to be undocumented as the documentation only mentions stylesheet urls.

Answer (score 1):

You need to change the content.css in the main ckeditor folder or add the following setting http://docs.ckeditor.com/#!/api/CKEDITOR.config-cfg-contentsCss

Comment: I actually have css in the contentsCSS field in the config, and it has also not applied.

Comment: Are you sure this css is accessible?
Can you provide the code you are using to add this css/creating the editor?

Comment: I've now tried removing contetsCSS so it should default to "contents.css" in the ckeditor root according to that page. When I make changes to contents.css they do not seem to be applied. I have a long config setup, I'll just have to remove it all and add it back in a piece at a time

Comment: Always remember to hard refresh your page for configuration changes.

Comment: Done that. I've even opened a different browser to try it out, no effect

Comment: Is it possible that you are getting your ckeditor scripts from a cdn?

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like your CSS styles are being overridden - try adding !important to each style like below:

```
.cke_editable { 
color: #fff!important; 
font-size: 14px!important; 
font-family: "Calibri"!important;
}
```